# Calculating age in years, days, months and hours in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am nery new to matlab. 
I want to calculate the age of a person in years, days, months and hours in matlab?
The user inputs his/her date of birth in **DD/MM/YYYY** format. Such as i am entering my DOB as 27/11/1989 how i can find my current age?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at this page: http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/bspgcx2-1.html

I'd use [datenum](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/datenum.html) for converting the input to a serial date number. Then subtract [now](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/now.html), and use [datestr](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/datestr.html) for converting the result back to a readable string in you desired 'DD/MM/YYYY' format.

Example: http://www.mathworks.nl/support/solutions/en/data/1-3W2LZP/index.html?product=SL&solution=1-3W2LZP

Full code (read and understand it, look at the links I provided!)

```
str='27/11/1989';

birth_numdate=datenum(str,'DD/mm/YYYY');
myage=datestr(now-birth_numdate,'DD/mm/YYYY');
```

As you can see, you should use `'mm'` instead of `'MM'` ('MM' corresponds to 'minutes' instead of 'months'.

Or you can use datevec, which would give you a vector containing #years, months, days, hours, minutes and seconds:

```
vec_myage=datevec(now-birth_numdate);
```

which results on my pc in:

```
ans =
   23.0000    8.0000    9.0000   22.0000   52.0000    7.1783
```

Now go find out in which timezone I live ;)